# Vue 3 - Add Query String Parameter to URL via $router

Tags: vue.js

I have an app that uses Vue 3 with the [Vue Router (v4)](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript). In this app, there's a button. When the button is clicked, I want to add a query string parameter to the current route. In an attempt to do this, I'm currently using the following approach:

```
console.log('updating the query string...');
let qs = this.$route.query;
qs.id = '[some GUID]';
this.$router.push({ query: qs });
console.log('query string updated!');
```

This code runs. However, the URL in the address bar does not get updated. An error is *not* posted to the console window either. My question is how do I add a query string parameter to the URL via the Vue Router?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share actualy value of `qs.id` ?

Comment: @scar-2018 Sure. The value is `c76e5a12-d38e-4d1e-8e0a-d273464d7453`

Comment: Thanks. `push` function needs the path to which the page redirects. So you can put router name or path as the first key.